# If statement break down

Tags: excel-2010

`=IF(CB8="",0,(IF($I8="NY",(IF(CB8<1,1,0)),(IF(CB8<2,1,)))))`

What does the `""` represent with no statement in the middle?

Whats does the `)))))` represent?

I have not used if statements to this existent.

Comment: What does the `))` in `1*(2-(4+3))` represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In functions you have to close every `(` with an `)`just like normal mathematics.

therefor you there are many `)` in the end of this function.

The `""`  stands for an empty string